# How to pass selected value between routes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, ember-data

I am quite new to the EmberJS.

This is my model: **book.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.attr('string'),
    picture: DS.attr('string'),
    buyer: DS.attr('string'),
    bought: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date', { defaultValue() { return new Date(); } })
});
```

I have the following route:
**Books.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('book');
    }   
});
```

and a bit from corresponding **books.hbs**

```
{{#each model as |book|}}
        <div class="book-container col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="details col-md-12">
                        <h3 class="product-title">Title {{book.title}}</h3>
                        <p class="product-description">Author:{{book.author}}</p>
                        {{#link-to 'books.give' }} Buy {{/link-to}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{{/each}}
```

This code returns all the books that I currently store in the app.

The idea is to get selected `Book` object from **books.hbs** and display it in **give.hbs**.

I wanted to use this line

`{{#link-to 'books.give' }} Buy {{/link-to}}`

to pass single a single book from **books.hbs** to **give.hbs**, but I don't know how to do that and if its the way to go..

In **gift.hbs** I partially invented a very inefficient way of doing it by looping all the books again and if the title is a match then display it...

```
  {{#each model as |book|}}
    {{#if (eq book.title "Harry Potter")}}
      <h2><b>{{book.title}}</b></h2>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
```

Obviously the "Harry Potter" string is hard-coded but it could have been passed from **books.hbs** and that would do the trick since my data is relatively small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how do you want to represent URL.
if it's `books/give/bookId` => then go for [dynamic segments](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments)
if its `books/give?bookId=1` => then go for [query params](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/query-params/) implementation

Inside `books.give` route get the particular book record using [findRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord) and use it.

Comment: Thanks @kumkanillam for giving me an idea to solve this.
I have chosen the way with dynamic segments.
I mixed up a bit the naming, instead of 'give' i should been using 'book'.
The problem was that I already had a book route which I was using for creating new records.

Comment: May be you can use `give` route and map it to different path something like `this.route('give',{path:'/:book_id'})` . you can play with [AlexSpeller route diagonal](http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/route/post). Let me know if you find any issues for using dynamic segments.

Comment: My routes are now just fine.  AlexSpeller's website was extremely helpful.
Everything works perfectly. The last question is how do i call my Object inside gift.hbs ? I tried book.title, but still no success

Comment: You can pass dynamic param book id from link-to helper like ` {{#link-to 'books.give' book.id }}` and get it in gift route model hook params like this `model (params){ return this.get ("store").findRecord('book',params.bookId); }` ...i am on phone i will try to provide ember twiddle tommorrow.